# 配列内のツリー構造を別の配列と合わせたい

Tags: javascript, typescript

この質問はほぼマルチポストです。元の質問はこちらです。https://teratail.com/questions/140995
teratailの方での質問の仕方に問題を感じたのもあり、より簡略化した質問をこちらにさせて頂きました。
ご指摘頂いたので上記追記致します。

```
let objectList = [

  {
    objectId : 1,
    objectName : "オブジェクト1",
    isLeaf : false,
    children : []
  },
  {
    objectId : 2,
    objectName : "オブジェクト2",
    isLeaf : true
  },
  {
    objectId : 3,
    objectName : "オブジェクト3",
    isLeaf : false, 
    children : []
  },
  {
    objectId : 4,
    objectName : "オブジェクト4",
    isLeaf : true
  },
  {
    objectId : 5,
    objectName : "オブジェクト5",
    isLeaf : false,
    children : []
  },

]
```

このような配列があった場合に

```
let updatedObjectList = [
  {
    objectId : 5,
    objectName : "オブジェクト5",
    isLeaf : false,
    children : []
  },
  {
    objectId : 3,
    objectName : "オブジェクト3",
    isLeaf : false,
    children : [
      {
        objectId : 2,
        objectName : "オブジェクト2",
        isLeaf : true
      },
      {
        objectId : 1,
        objectName : "オブジェクト1",
        isLeaf : false,
        children : [
          {
            objectId : 4,
            objectName : "オブジェクト4",
            objectList : [],
            isLeaf : true
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

こちらのupdatedObjectListと同じ構造に、objectListをしたいです...。
ただし、objectList = updatedObjectList とするのではなく、
**objectListをソートすることで、updatedObjectListと同じ構造にしたいです。**

```
//linq-es2015使用しております
let objectList = this.objectList

this.objectList = []

for(var i = 0; i < updatedObjectList.length; i++){
            this.objectList.unshift(Enumerable.asEnumerable(objectList).Where(x=>x.objectId==updatedObjectList[i].objectId).ToArray()[0])
}
```

もし、childrenという概念がなく、ただ順番を入れ替えるだけなら上のような形でできるのですが、コードがスマートじゃないし、階層構造をどう表現するのか分からなく、困っております...。
また逆に、階層構造を解除する(childrenに含めれたオブジェクトを外に出す)こともあります。
どのような関数を作ればいいのか...。
教えてくだされば幸いです(>_<)

Comment: parentはどうやって決めていますか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/140995

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！
parentになれるオブジェクトは、isLeaf:falseというパラメーターを持ちます。
上のupdatedObjectListのパターンは一例にすぎないです。
例えば、このようなupdatedObjectListがきた場合にどのようにソートすれば再現できるのかという質問になります。
わかりづらくて申し訳ないです

Comment: マルチポストすみません、teratailの方の質問の仕方があまりよくなかったので、少し形を変えて質問したのですが...。この質問は削除した方がいいですかね？

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローはマルチポスト禁止ではありません。ですから、何もしなくともよいですが、できれば、[マルチポストは何か問題があるのですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2419/3054)で指摘されている内容、特に「マルチポストであることと、他の投稿先を明記する」を満たしていただければと思います。（Teratail 側には別のルールがあるかも知れません）

Comment: ありがとうございます。では一応、マルチポストである追記をしておきます。それと回答を頂き、正しく動きましたので、teratailの方でもその報告を致します。本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

性能上の問題が出ていないならば、入れ替えのような難しいことは考えずに、一から順に作り直すのが楽だと思います。

とりあえず、ごく素直に考えると以下のようになりました。
作り直す前に元のオブジェクト達をどこかに保存しておかなければならないので、以下ではそれを `mkObjectTable` にやらせていますが、質問の例のように元のリストが単純な一次元配列なら、そのままコピーしておけばいいですね。

```
type MyObj = {
    objectId: number,
    children?: MyObj[],
}

function mkObjectTable(list: MyObj[], table: MyObj[] = []): MyObj[] {
    for (const o of list) {
        table[o.objectId] = o
        if (o.children != null) {
            mkObjectTable(o.children, table)
        }
    }
    return table
}

function copyStructure(src: MyObj[], dest: MyObj[], table: MyObj[] = mkObjectTable(dest)) {
    dest.length = 0
    for (const srcObj of src) {
        const destObj = table[srcObj.objectId]
        dest.push(destObj)
        if (srcObj.children != null && srcObj.children.length != 0) {
            if (destObj.children == null) {
                destObj.children = []
            }
            copyStructure(srcObj.children, destObj.children, table)
        } else if (destObj.children != null) {
            destObj.children.length = 0
        }
    }
}

copyStructure(updatedObjectList, objectList)
```

---

> これって参照渡しみたいになってるのでしょうか

JavaScriptのオブジェクトは配列を含め、参照型です。
ですから、関数に配列を渡すと関数内で書き変えられるという意味で「参照渡しみたい」と言ってよいと思います。
（正確には「参照の値渡し」かも知れません。私はこのへんの用語はよく解りません）

Comment: 本当にありがとうございます！！！
できました！！！
これって参照渡しみたいになってるのでしょうか、関数の中で   this.objectList =  
みたいな書かれ方がされていないのにできました！

Comment: @nichika さん、当サイトでは問題の解決に一番役立った回答を「承認」するのがお約束です。(回答の見出しの横にチェックマークアイコンか何かが出ているはず。) mjy さんの回答で問題が解決できたのなら、「承認」も忘れずにお願いします。

Comment: すみません、今気づいたのですが、今のままだと、元のobjectListにchildrenを持ったオブジェクトがあり、updatedObjectListではそのオブジェクトがchildrenの外に出された場合にうまくいきません...。childrenに、外に出したはずのオブジェクトが残ってしまいます...。

Comment: @nichika とりあえず、元のオブジェクトの `children` を切り詰める処理を追加しました。

Comment: 凄すぎます、できました。ありがとうございます...。